# Running JUnit test on Controller results in UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: java, spring, gradle, junit

This is my test (Gradle) Spring boot project that allows users retrieve country info from a db via RESTful web service.
I can run the application (gradlew bootRun) and it works as expected. But my JUnit test ran on ServiceControllerUnitTest throws an exception. I am new to Spring so I assume that I am probably missing something pretty obvious, most likely related to my testing configuration.

[image]

**build.gradle**

```
    dependencies {

        // Spring Boot
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services')
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")

        compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.1.4.RELEASE'
        compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.6.Final'
        compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.6.Final'
        compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
        compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.7'
        compile 'org.javassist:javassist:3.15.0-GA'
        compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.31'
        compile 'commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4'  

        // Unit Testing
        testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
        testCompile("junit:junit:4.12")
        testCompile("org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19")
        testCompile("com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path-assert:0.8.1")

    }
```

**Error**

```
    [main] ERROR org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@4e1d422d] to prepare test instance [com.pckg.controller.ServiceControllerUnitTest@2a22ad2b]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.pckg.controller.ServiceControllerUnitTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'controller'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.pckg.controller.ServiceController' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
```

**ServiceController.java**

```
    @RestController
    public class ServiceController {

        @Autowired
        ICountryService countryService;

        @RequestMapping("/country")
        public Country getCountryByName(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = true) String countryName) {

            Country country = countryService.getCountryByName(countryName);
            return country;
        }

        @RequestMapping("/continent")
        public List<Country> getCountryByContinent(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = true) String continent) {

            List<Country> countries = countryService.getCountriesByContinent(continent);
            return countries;
        }

        @RequestMapping("/countries")
        public List<Country> getAllCountries() {
            List<Country> countries = countryService.getAllCountries();
            return countries;

        }
    }
```

**ServiceControllerUnitTest.java**

```
    @Category(UnitTest.class)
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class)
    public class ServiceControllerUnitTest extends UnitTest {

        private MockMvc mockMvc;

        @Autowired
        private ServiceController controller;

        @Override
        @Before
        public void setUp() {
            super.setUp();
            mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
        }
```

**UnitTest.java**

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest(classes = UnitTestConfig.class)
    @WebAppConfiguration
    public abstract class UnitTest {
        @Before
        public void setUp() {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        }
    }
```

**UnitTestConfig.java**

```
    public class UnitTestConfig extends MockServletConfig {

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out and it turns out that it was my @ContextConfiguration in the ServiceControllerUnitTest.java that was referencing an incorrect file. I used two files in my application **App.java** and **AppConfig.java** (in the screenshot above).

My App.java contained only the main method.

**App.java**

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class App extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
        }
```

And my AppConfig.java contained my @Bean declarations.

**AppConfig.java**

e.g.

```
    @Bean
    public HibernateTemplate getHibernateTemplate() {
        return new HibernateTemplate(getSessionFactory());
    }
```

I actually referenced the **AppConfig.java** file in the **@ContextConfiguration** annotation instead of the **App.java** file.

**ServiceControllerUnitTest.java**

```
@Category(UnitTest.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class) // >>>> issue here
public class ServiceControllerUnitTest extends UnitTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ServiceController controller;

    @Override
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        super.setUp();
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
    }
```

I have combined code from both files App.java and AppConfig.java into one file AppConfig.java under the com.pckg package.

All is good and working now.